# AWK output help

Tags: awk

I am currently writing something to parse some apache logs, yet the `system` command seems to be putting itself above print. Haven't done a whole lot with `awk`, so it could be something very simple.

```
IFS=$'\n' 
for ja in `cat test.apache.access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -3`
do 
echo $ja|awk '{print "Count\tIP\t\tNSLookup"}{print $1"\t",$2,"\t\t",system("nslookup " $2"|grep name")}'
done
```

What I get :

```
Count   IP              NSLookup
RR.ZZ.YY.XX.in-addr.arpa      name = ja.server.net.
241      XX.YY.ZZ.RR           0
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Count   IP              NSLookup
241      XX.YY.ZZ.RR          RR.ZZ.YY.XX.in-addr.arpa      name = ja.server.net.
```

Comment: Apologies, but I have no idea how to format on this thing

Comment: please provide some sample logs, and explain what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: on echo $ja, try this: echo $(echo $ja). I dont know if it will help, but it removes new lines.

Comment: This is what log resolvers are for...

Comment: If you have to use `awk` then note that `system()` will send output to STDOUT and the return code is the result (that's why you get a `0` on your line).  If you want to capture this for processing then you need to do a `system(..) | getline name ; print "..."name` type call.

Comment: @Rahul I suspect, from trying with some of my own, that the input file is a standard apache `access_log`.  The first field is an IP address (which are sorted and counted), and the rest is irrelevant (for this script).

Comment: Went for lunch, so sorry for the delay, and thanks for the reformat! It is a generic access log that I want to be able to see where the most connections are from, and do a lookup on them.

Answer (score 2):

Your script need to be reordered a little and *awk* do not need at all

```
echo -e 'Count\tIP\tNSLookup'
while read count line ; do
    echo -ne "$count\t$line\t"
    nslookup $line | grep name
done < <(cut -d' ' -f1 test.apache.access_log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -3)
```

And sure it can be done by awk only

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
        OFS="\t"
        print "Count", "IP", "NSLookup"
    }
    {
        A[$1]++
    }
    END{
        for(a in A){
            i = 3
            while(i > 0 && A[a] > A[B[i]]){
                B[i+1] = B[i]
                i--
            }
            B[i+1] = a
        }
        for(b=1; b<4; b++){
            "nslookup "B[b]" | grep name" | getline ns
            print A[B[b]], B[b], ns
        }
    }
    ' test.apache.access_log
```

Comment: `s/sort -n/sort/` - you're sorting IP addresses.

Comment: The `sort` doesn't need the `-n` because we just need a consistent ordering, so `uniq -c` can count unique lines; we re-order with `sort -rn` afterwards.  It could be any data; doesn't matter :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris @SatoKatsura Yes, and I see that OP need `1.100.1.1` after `1.99.1.1` therefore `-n` or `-V` should be in

Comment: No, the OP wants the output in "most frequently used first" order; that's what the final `sort -rn` does.  The intermediate part of the pipeline ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Folks, thanks for all the help. Ill have a quick look at this in a little while and confirm it works, which I assume it wil, and then close off the question.
Thanks for all the help folks!